# Sum divides Factorial

Tags: number-theory, summation, divisibility, factorial

Is there a prime number $p$ such that,
$$\frac{p(p-1)}{2}\mid (p-1)! $$ or does this only hold for composites?

I have extensively tried multiple examples and even tried to prove that this only holds for a composite n and have gotten this far:

Suppose $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\mid (n-1)!$. Then $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\cdot k=(n-1)!$
$\Leftrightarrow k=\frac{(n-1)!}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}\Leftrightarrow k=\frac{2(n-1)!}{n(n-1)}\Leftrightarrow k=\frac{2(n-2)!}{n}$. Yet I am at a miss right now and am not sure where to go from here.

Help if you would.

Comment: This is true for $p=2$ only. Otherwise $p$ is odd, and also $p\not\nmid (p-1)!$, hence not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is (essentially) done.
$k$ must be an integer. But, if $n=p$ is prime, then when will $\frac{2(p-2)!}{p}$ be integral?

> Never, as $p\nmid 2(p-2)!$ for prime $p>2$.  Note that $p = 2$ is a prime that *does* satisfy your condition though.

Comment: Then can I use this to show that n must be composite?

Comment: @SaturdayMornQB if $n$ isn't prime, then (if $n$ exist that are solutions) they must be composite.  So, if you can show solutions besides $n = 2$ exist, they must all be composite.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Mark